# update a record using angularjs

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs

i am creating a web app in `C#` using `angularjs` i have multiple records in my app I want to update thode record, i created web service and required js files for updating i just want to know how i need to print the previous value on the textbox and dropdownlist

```
<input type="text" ng-model="uvenuename" ng-init="uvenuename='{{updateparam.VenueName}}'" value="{{updateparam.VenueName}}" style="margin-left: 5%;" placeholder="Venue Name" text="" height="30" />

<input type="text" ng-model="uvenueadd" ng-init="uvenueadd='{{updateparam.Venueadd}}'" value="{{updateparam.Venueadd}}" style="margin-left: 5%;" placeholder="Venue Address" text="" height="30" />
```

i did something like this but if i want to change a single textbox (`let see`) i only changed venue name and update the record, venue address is showing like `{{updateparam.Venueadd}}` and my dropdownlist is showing me blank spaces

```
<select ng-model="ulocation">
   <option ng-repeat="k in blocation" value="{{k.jlocation}}">
        {{k.jlocation}}
   </option>
</select>
```

here is my dropdown,  how to get over these flows?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of use ng-init and value to try to maintain the binding between your view and the variables  you should use just the ng-model to use the double binding of AngularJS. It's necessary that you don't use a primitive data type in the ng-model in order to make it works well.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="data.uvenuename" style="margin-left: 5%;" placeholder="Venue Name" text="" height="30" />

<input type="text" ng-model="data.uvenueadd" style="margin-left: 5%;" placeholder="Venue Address" text="" height="30" />
```

The same for your select element

```
<select ng-model="data.ulocation">
   <option ng-repeat="k in blocation" value="{{k.jlocation}}">
      {{k.jlocation}}
   </option>
</select>
```

In the select tag the var data.ulocation will be updated with the value in the attr value in the option tag.

The data variable should be something like:

```
$scope.data = {
    uvenuename: "",
    uvenueadd: "",
    ulocation: ""
}
```

Comment: textbox is working but dropdown is not working still getting blank space

Comment: What is the value of the "blocation" variable?

Comment: there are multiple values of blocation

Comment: I suppose that, but I want to know if it's an array, an object or what. if you can post the value of this var it could be useful to solve your question.

Comment: the only two possible reasons that you don't have options in the select element it's because the blocation var is empty or the object into it doesn't have the property jlocation and you have empty options.

Comment: `{"zone":[{"jzone":"North"},{"jzone":"East"},{"jzone":"South"},{"jzone":"West"}]}` this is how my data is coming

Comment: Then your ng-repeat should by like "ng-repeat='k in blocation.zone' " and into the options use the k.jzone and not the jlocation as you have.

Comment: ohh sorry sorry

Comment: `{"location":[{"jlocation":"\u003c--Select--\u003e"},{"jlocation":"Angul"},{"jlocation":"Balangir"},{"jlocation":"Balasore"},{"jlocation":"Bargarh"},{"jlocation":"Bemetara "},{"jlocation":"Bhagalpur"},{"jlocation":"Bhilai"},{"jlocation":"Bhubaneshwar"},{"jlocation":"Bilaspur"},{"jlocation":"Champa"},{"jlocation":"Cuttak"},{"jlocation":"Deoghar"},{"jlocation":"Dhenkanal"},{"jlocation":"Dumka"},{"jlocation":"Godda"},{"jlocation":"Hazaribagh"},{"jlocation":"Jasidih"},{"jlocation":"Jharsuguda"},{"jlocation":"Kolkata "},{"jlocation":"Korba"},{"jlocation":"Miyapur"},{"jlocation":"Sambalpur"}]}`

Comment: the data is coming like this

Comment: Then the same, the ng-repeat should use the blocation.location array and leave the options just like you have it now.